# Apache's Digest Authentication md5(user:realm:password) is not the hash inside .htdigest file

Tags: apache, hash, digest-authentication

on Apache's docs site:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/password_encryptions.html#digest

They say that the hash of the password used for `Digest Authentication` created with the `htdigest` utility:

```
$ htdigest -c ./.htdigest "A Realm" user
Adding password for user in realm A Realm.
New password:
Re-type new password:
$ cat ./.htdigest
user:A Realm:879af2190fce9012039001fecbb23412
```

**879af2190fce9012039001fecbb23412** = md5(user:A Realm:password). However, if I type:

```
$ echo "user:A Realm:password" | md5sum
e77ed25bc7d1fe5ffe9f827346b2cd7b    -
```

I get another hash, which is not the one inside `./.htdigest`.

How then Apache computes the MD5 hash inside `./.htdigest` when I create the file with `htdigest`?

Comment: If you're thinking of using digest authentication, don't.  It's no longer secure.  Instead use plain HTTP auth or a simple auth combined with HTTPS (TLS 1.1 or better)

Comment: No, I don't want to use it. I just wanted to understand how that hash was computed because I am curious, do you know how?

Comment: It should be following the standards or it wouldn't inter-operate with browsers.  I'm not sure why it's different.

Comment: I close the post cause I have found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394552/htdigest-file-format

Comment: Ok, echo throws an extra character at the end.  The result is still different though.  I suggest you read a detailed spec.  My guess is it's got something to do with the Realm containing a space or something.  Try the above without a space in the name for the realm.

Comment: Oh, sure  I didn't see that other answer.  But I did figure out it was echo.  The result is still wrong though!

Comment: That was an example to show the use case, if I try it now it works for the users inside the .htdigest` I created